# Resample script, how to make it work in an existing website with different img urls

Tags: php, image, image-manipulation

I've being provided with a code which can resize/resample images from a url. I would like to have this code implemented in my website. The resample script is pretty straightforward, but I really don't know how to make it work with the rest of the website. I really hope someone can help me with this problem.

**The code which produces a thumbnail is the following, this is a part of the code at the bottom of this post**

```
$img_attributes= 'style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px"' . ' title="' . htmlspecialchars($product['product_name']) . '"';
```

**This is the code which can resample a image:**

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'http://valplibrary.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/5b585d_merry-christmas-blue-style.jpg';
$percent = 0.5; // percentage of resize

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

**This is the whole code which is partly responsible for the thumnails at my website.**

```
<?php 
if( !defined( '_VALID_MOS' ) && !defined( '_JEXEC' ) ) die( 'Direct Access to '.basename(__FILE__).' is not allowed.' ); 
/**
* This is the theme's function file.
* It allows you to declare additional functions and classes
* that may be used in your templates 
*
* @version $Id: theme.php 1427 2008-06-18 20:04:01Z soeren_nb $
* @package VirtueMart
* @subpackage themes
* @copyright Copyright (C) 2006-2008 soeren - All rights reserved.
* @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
* VirtueMart is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
* to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
* is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
* other free or open source software licenses.
* See /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
*
* http://virtuemart.net
*/
global $mainframe;

// include the stylesheet for this template

$vm_mainframe->addScriptDeclaration("window.templatePath = '".JURI::base()."';");
$vm_mainframe->addStyleSheet( VM_THEMEURL.'theme.css' );
$vm_mainframe->addScript( VM_THEMEURL.'theme.js' );


// Reset of VM defaults JS bits
define ("_MOOTOOLS_LOADED", "1");
define ("_SLIMBOX_LOADED", "1");
vmRequest::setVar("usefetchscript", 0, "session");

class rokCommonHTML extends vmCommonHTML {
    function getRokboxImageLink($image_link, $text, $title='', $image_group='') {
        if( $image_group ) {
            $image_group = '('.$image_group.')';
        }

        $img = str_replace(JURI::base(), '', $image_link);
        if ($img_size = @getimagesize($img)) $size = "[{$img_size[0]} {$img_size[1]}]";
        else $size = "";
        $link = rokCommonHTML::hyperLink( $image_link, $text, '', $title, 'rel="rokbox'.$size.$image_group.'"' );

        return $link;
    }
}
// End of Reset

class vmTheme extends vmTemplate  {

    function vmTheme() {
        parent::vmTemplate();

        // Removing this, since we're loading it already from our template
        //vmCommonHTML::loadMooTools();
    }

    function vmBuildFullImageLink( $product ) {
        global $VM_LANG;

        $product_image = '';

        $img_attributes= 'style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px"' . ' title="' . htmlspecialchars($product['product_name']) . '"';


        /* Wrap the Image into an URL when applicable */
        if ( @$product["product_url"] ) {
            $product_image = "<a href=\"". $product["product_url"]."\" title=\"".$product['product_name']."\" target=\"_blank\">";
            $product_image .= ps_product::image_tag($product['product_thumb_image'], $img_attributes, 0);
            $product_image .= "</a>";
        }
        /* Show the Thumbnail with a Link to the full IMAGE */
        else {
            if( empty($product['product_full_image'] ) ) {
                $product_image = "<img src=\"".VM_THEMEURL.'images/'.NO_IMAGE."\" alt=\"".$product['product_name']."\" border=\"0\" />";
            }
            else {
                // file_exists doesn't work on remote files,
                // so returns false on remote files
                // This should fix the "Long Page generation bug"
                if( file_exists( IMAGEPATH.'product/'.$product['product_full_image'] )) {

                    /* Get image width and height */
                    if( $image_info = @getimagesize(IMAGEPATH.'product/'.$product['product_full_image'] ) ) {
                        $width = $image_info[0] + 20;
                        $height = $image_info[1] + 20;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $width = 640;
                    $height= 480;
                }
                if( stristr( $product['product_full_image'], "http" ) ) {
                    $imageurl = $product['product_full_image'];
                }
                else {
                    $imageurl = IMAGEURL.'product/'.rawurlencode( $VM_LANG->convert($product['product_full_image']));
                }
                /* Build the "See Bigger Image" Link */
                if( @$_REQUEST['output'] != "pdf" && $this->get_cfg('useLightBoxImages', 1 ) ) {
                    $link = $imageurl;
                    $text = ps_product::image_tag($product['product_thumb_image'], $img_attributes, 0)."<br/>".$VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_FLYPAGE_ENLARGE_IMAGE');

                    //$product_image = vmCommonHTML::getLightboxImageLink( $link, $text, $product['product_name'], 'product'.$product['product_id'] );
                    $product_image = rokCommonHTML::getRokboxImageLink( $link, $text, $product['product_name'], 'product'.$product['product_id'] );
                }
                elseif( @$_REQUEST['output'] != "pdf" ) {
                    $link = $imageurl;
                    $text = ps_product::image_tag($product['product_thumb_image'], $img_attributes, 0)."<br/>".$VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_FLYPAGE_ENLARGE_IMAGE');
                    // vmPopupLink can be found in: htmlTools.class.php
                    $product_image = vmPopupLink( $link, $text, $width, $height );
                }
                else {
                    $product_image = "<a href=\"$imageurl\" target=\"_blank\">"
                                    . ps_product::image_tag($product['product_thumb_image'], $img_attributes, 0)
                                    . "</a>";
                }
            }
        }
        return $product_image;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a list of all additional images
     *
     * @param int $product_id
     * @param array $images
     * @return string
     */
    function vmlistAdditionalImages( $product_id, $images, $title='', $limit=1000 ) {
        global $sess;
        $html = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $images as $image ) { 
            $thumbtag = ps_product::image_tag( $image->file_name, 'class="browseProductImage"', 1, 'product', $image->file_image_thumb_width, $image->file_image_thumb_height );
            $fulladdress = $sess->url( 'index2.php?page=shop.view_images&amp;image_id='.$image->file_id.'&amp;product_id='.$product_id.'&amp;pop=1' );

            if( $this->get_cfg('useLightBoxImages', 1 )) {
                //$html .= vmCommonHTML::getLightboxImageLink( $image->file_url, $thumbtag, $title ? $title : $image->file_title, 'product'.$product_id );
                $html .= rokCommonHTML::getRokboxImageLink( $image->file_url, $thumbtag, $title ? $title : $image->file_title, 'product'.$product_id );
            }
            else {
                $html .= vmPopupLink( $fulladdress, $thumbtag, 640, 550 );
            }
            $html .= ' ';
            if( ++$i > $limit ) break;
        }
        return $html;
    }
    /**
     * Builds the "more images" link
     *
     * @param array $images
     */
    function vmMoreImagesLink( $images ) {
        global $mosConfig_live_site, $VM_LANG, $sess;
        /* Build the JavaScript Link */
        $url = $sess->url( "index2.php?page=shop.view_images&amp;flypage=".@$_REQUEST['flypage']."&amp;product_id=".@$_REQUEST['product_id']."&amp;category_id=".@$_REQUEST['category_id']."&amp;pop=1" );
        $text = $VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_MORE_IMAGES').'('.count($images).')';
        $image = vmCommonHTML::imageTag( VM_THEMEURL.'images/more_images.png', $text, '', '16', '16' );

        return vmPopupLink( $url, $image.'<br />'.$text, 640, 550, '_blank', '', 'screenX=100,screenY=100' );
    }


    // Your code here please...

}
?>
```

Comment: Posting some code sample you found and asking us "make this work for me" is just plain lazy.  Figuring out how this works will be both rewarding and educational for you, you're never going to become a good coder if you beg other people to do your work for you.

Comment: I understand that, personally I don't even know where to start. I just don't have the knowlegde how to do this, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

A bit wall of code ish, but having given it a quick look, the two methods of doing what you want are either to have the resample script take a filename argument. For example, in the HTML you could put

```
src="resample.php?myjpg.jpg"
```

And alter the respamler (You need error checking as well, people could do nasty things)

```
<?php
$filename = 'http://valplibrary.files.wordpress.com/'.key($_GET);
```

The other method is to use htaccess (or the IIS alternative if you don't use Apache) to rewrite urls, which is a neater solution. Create a directory called thumbs, and put the script and the htacess file in.

Use the .htaccess file to match

```
http://valplibrary.files.wordpress.com/thumbs/(.*)
```

And rewrite the url to

```
resample.php?$1 #(where $1 is the value in (.*))
```

I hope these give you ideas.

Comment: I have 0.5 understanding of php and this goes way out of my league. Can you explain me what do do please?