# Resize an image direct from url using php

Tags: php, image-processing

I am not sure if this can be done so posting here.I have an image stored in a web server.For eg http://www.abc.com/myimage.png

Now I want to resize that image but without having it in my local.So it will be a direct image resize from url.

Please suggest if there is any guide or example.

Comment: What's wrong with your [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=image+resizing+php)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resize image from url and make the size of the image smaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960953/how-to-resize-image-from-url-and-make-the-size-of-the-image-smaller)

Comment: Still searching mate...couldn't find yet...he is ignoring me now.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/gmagick.resizeimage.php
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: http://pixlr.com/developer/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use the GD library, you can use this function.

**A word of caution**

```
Resizing images on the fly can really slow down the page
```

Code:

```
function getImageXY( $image, $imgDimsMax=140 ) {
    $top = 0;
    $left = 0;

    $aspectRatio= 1;    // deafult aspect ratio...keep the image as is.

    // set the default dimensions.
    $imgWidth   = $imgDimsMax;
    $imgHeight  = $imgDimsMax;

    list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $image );

    if( $width == $height ) {
        // if the image is less than ( $imgDimsMax x $imgDimsMax ), use it as is..
        if( $width < $imgDimsMax ) {
            $imgWidth   = $width;
            $imgHeight  = $height;
            $top = $imgDimsMax - $imgWidth;
            $left = $imgDimsMax - $imgWidth;
        }
    } else {
        if( $width > $height ) {
            // set $imgWidth to $imgDimsMax and resize $imgHeight proportionately
            $aspectRatio    = $imgWidth / $width;
            $imgHeight      = floor ( $height * $aspectRatio );
            $top = ( $imgDimsMax - $imgHeight ) / 2;
        } else if( $width < $height ) {
            // set $imgHeight to $imgDimsMax and resize $imgWidth proportionately
            $aspectRatio    = $imgHeight / $height;
            $imgWidth       = floor ( $width * $aspectRatio );
            $left = ( $imgDimsMax - $imgWidth ) / 2;
        }
    }

    return '<img src="' . $image . '" width="' . $imgWidth . '" height="' . $imgHeight . '" style="position:relative;display:inline;top:'.$top.'px;left:'.$left.'px;" />';
}
```

This assumes a max image size of 140px. You can change it as per your wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh. The code is working. I am wondering if we can resize it to 376 x 188 px.

Comment: If you want the image to be exactly 376x188, then you have to use gd library. else, pass `$imgDimsMax=376`, it will resize accordingly.

Comment: Thanks..I will look out for that one.

Answer (score 1):

Use phpthumb. It creates thumbnail of any image on the fly.

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/