# Create Image From Amazon S3 url

Tags: php, yii, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using YII Framework. I need to display image from Amazon S3.

S3 url is like :-https://s3.amazonaws.com/qbprod/70dcdd564f5d4b15b32b975be15e4a1200.

need to crop the image and display in browser without storing in local system path. Is it Possible?

I came across several examples but not found any example to modify the image and display in browser on the fly without local storage.

Comment: Do you want to crop or resize?

Comment: thanks for the response kumar. Need to crop and resize.

Comment: then try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960953/how-to-resize-image-from-url-and-make-the-size-of-the-image-smaller

Comment: Thanks for the response. Already tried out this stuff. For https url it not work. so i accessed it using the CURL. I am not sure how to handle the response stream from curl response