# Rewrite image URL to a script which resizes the requested image

Tags: php, image, apache, mod-rewrite, resize

Using Apache's mod_rewrite, how can I rewrite the following URL

```html
http://us.louisvuitton.com/images/is/image/lv/1/VE_DI1_L/louis-vuitton-fall-2015-campaign--Series3_DI1.jpg?wid=1360&hei=633
```

so that it points to another page like the following URL

```html
http://us.louisvuitton.com/image.php?file=images/is/image/lv/1/VE_DI1_L/louis-vuitton-fall-2015-campaign--Series3_DI1.jpg&wid=1360&hei=633
```

which should output the image in a custom size?

--

About the possible duplicate:

It would look like

```
server.com/thumb.php?file=images/1.jpg&wid=120
```

What I want should look like

```
server.com/images/1.jpg?wid=120
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resize image from url and make the size of the image smaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960953/how-to-resize-image-from-url-and-make-the-size-of-the-image-smaller)

Comment: Well basically the wid and hei properties are just there as the values that will be given to the image as respectively the its Width and Height. By using the     "?wid=1360&hei=633" if you mean that you want to change those properties you will just have to replace those value. On thing you wanna keep in mind if that you want to keep to ratio of the image for it to stay nice to see.

Comment: You might want to look into [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Comment: You would have to make use of the URL rewriting module for your web server.

Comment: @vonUbisch No, it's not a duplicate.. The answer in there is a .php page that resizes the given the url.. What I want is to direcly resize on the own url.

Comment: @Ítalo Andrade, with a few extra characters you can achieve your desired result. Replace `$new_width` with `$_GET['wid']` and so forth.

Comment: @bottus I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: @Anders Already found this on Google and there is no think alike.

Comment: @TinyGiant What that is?

Comment: @vonUbisch It would look like "http://server.com/thumb.php?file=images/1.jpg&wid=120" and what I want is "http://server.com/images/1.jpg?wid=120"

Comment: Basically, we would have to know what web server application you're using (e.g. apache, nginx, node.js) and what version of that web browser you're using. Then we can suggest a script to rewrite the requested URL internally to point to a different page other than the requested image and then create an image from a string obtained from an image file, then resize that image and output it to the browser. But, first I would recommend you do some research on URL rewriting for your web server rephrasing your question.

Comment: Rewrite your URL in your htaccess as @TinyGiant commented

Comment: @ÍtaloAndrade, what about [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php)?

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm using Apache

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify for those answering.

Comment: @vonUbisch Like "RewriteRule ^image/([^\.]+)$ thumb.php?file=$1 [NC,L]"(example, this doesnt worked)?

Comment: You also have to take into account the query string ([QSA](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString#Adding_to_the_Query_String))

Comment: @TinyGiant Thank you very much. But how do you know it's a script with rewrite? Even if I could use htaccess that i said to vonUbisch it would look like "server.com/images/1.jpg&wid=50" (& and not ?, because the ? would be on the htacess)

Comment: No it would rewrite internally, so you would request `/path/to/file.png?wid=num&hei=num` and the server would internally redirect to `/path/to/script.php?file=/path/to/file.png&wid=num&hei=nm` then you would have to create the `/path/to/script.php` which would check if `$_GET['file']` exists and then get the contents of that file, create an image from the returned string and output a resized image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) and changing the .htacess to:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images/([^?]+)\?w=([^&]+)&h([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /phpThumb.php?src=images2/%1&w=%2&h%3 [NC,L]

Options All
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Root/.htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images/is/image/lv/1/VE_DI1_L/([^?]+)\?wid=([^&]+)&hei=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /image.php?file=images/is/image/lv/1/VE_DI1_L/%1&wid=%2&hei=%3 [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Ty, I've complemented your answer and posted as new answer what I did that worked..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sweet little solution with no big config overhead that uses a PHP script to resize the images and an Apache rewrite rule to cache the resulting low resolution images in the file system:
https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/3236415